# Pull out side menu in iOS examples

Tags: ios

I have seen reveal menus like the one in Facebook app. But that is not I want. I would like to have an arrow and when u click the button the slide menu should slide out from hidden.

Is there any code examples or opensource libraries that is able to do this?

Need some guidance on this. Thanks..

For example, i have a button with an image called pull me and it is sitting at the bottom and when i pull it, the menu comes out on top of existing view..

Comment: menu should slide out from hidden, on top of existing view? the way UIPopover works, except that it should slide?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this functionality, you'll need to create a custom container controller class and instantiate it with child view controllers. The views of the child view controllers will be managed by the container controller using custom animations.

It would be better if you build your own container controller, but if you really need a library, here's one : http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/slide-navigation-view-controller

It manages sliding the primary/root view in any one of the 4 directions (up, left, down, right).

Hope this helps